# How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I've realized that Chrome, it seems, will not allow me to hide `<option>` in a `<select>`. Firefox will.

I need to hide the `<option>`s that match a search criteria. In the Chrome web tools I can see that they are correctly being set to `display: none;` by my JavaScript, but once then `<select>` menu is clicked they are shown.

How can I make these `<option>`s that match my search criteria NOT show when the menu is clicked?

Comment: Instead of hiding and showing on a search.  Try and populate the select depending on the search

Comment: I agree with Henesnarfel. If you are already doing a search or some kind of query, you should be able to just populate the ones that you want.

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/ZNWMw/) works fine for me in Chrome 16.0.912.77 m. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @mgibsonbr It doesn't work cross-browser.

Comment: @Henesnarfel There can be good reasons to hide options. For example, I had a page with a select listbox and links to hide or show items marked as inactive. No reason to keep multiple lists or query the server for a new list whenever the user changes that option.

Comment: @Jasper oh, you're right! The OP mentioned Chrome, so I tested on Chrome and Firefox, and assumed it would work elsewhere. But it really failed on Safari, Opera and IE6...

Comment: using jquery, have a copy of all options in masterVariable and tempVariable.
Remove the unwanted option tags from tempVariable.
When you want to show another set of option tags, just assign masterVariable content to tempVariable and remove option tags  from tempVariable again., This logic works in every browser.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have to implement two methods for hiding. `display: none` works for FF, but not Chrome or IE. So the second method is wrapping the `<option>` in a `<span>` with `display: none`. FF won't do it (technically invalid HTML, per the spec) but Chrome and IE will and it will hide the option.

EDIT: Oh yeah, I already implemented this in jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length == 0 )
            jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};
```

EDIT 2: Here's how you would use this function:

```
jQuery(selector).toggleOption(true); // show option
jQuery(selector).toggleOption(false); // hide option
```

EDIT 3: Added extra check suggested by @user1521986

Comment: This crazy method is the only one that actually worked completely cross-browser and didn't involve creating a faux-hidden select box hack.

Comment: Be careful with this. It seems to work great at first but somewhere along the line it stops. Here's a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yb6sk/9/

Comment: Though this solution does hide the element, any attempt to read the value of the `<select>` (using jQuery's `.val()`) will return `null`. I just tested this in Chrome 29, so Googlers beware!

Comment: It always returns the first option's value no matter what.

Comment: Interesting hack, but I would recommend avoiding "technically invalid HTML" if at all possible.

Comment: @Luke I'll keep that in mind when all browsers implement the same standards the same way. ;)

Comment: True, all browsers have different implementations. But one reason browsers cannot strictly implement the standard specs is because there is too much live code out there that doesn't follow the specs. IMO: If there are no other solutions, then by all means use a hack. But if you can follow the spec *and* solve your problem, why wouldn't you? It helps your code to play nice with others and helps to strengthen the spec.

Comment: @Mark thanks for your comment, but how would we then read the value of a hidden `<select>` field?

Comment: As a note, this will no longer work on Chrome, since Chrome will enforce that `span` can't appear in select elements.  Tried this on Chrome 60.0.3112.113

Comment: Safari won't accept this solution either. Though this method has fall. Don't know if there is another one.

Answer (score 126):

For HTML5, you can use the 'hidden' attribute.

```
<option hidden>Hidden option</option>
```

It is *not* supported by IE < 11. But if you need only to hide a few elements, maybe it would be better to just set the hidden attribute in combination with disabled in comparison to adding/removing elements or doing not semantically correct constructions.

```html
<select>  
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option hidden>Hidden Option</option>
</select>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp).

Comment: This is the modern answer. Ideally we're also setting this to `disabled` so  those browsers that don't support the [HTML5 global `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) will have some visual indication for the user.

Comment: How do you use this technique with CSS?

Comment: Does not work in Safari, Edge, nor IE.  [Bug for Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8351) is 10 years old, please help by updating existing patches.  Cannot find bug in Edge issue tracker.

Comment: A workaround for this is using `<option hidden disabled>`, so it hides in all good browsers and disables it on the others.

Comment: Looks like all green lights for `hidden`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=hidden

Comment: Looks like all green lights for `display:none` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71290421/2750743) answer truthfully states

Answer (score 39):

I would suggest that you do *not* use the solutions that use a `<span>` wrapper because it isn't valid HTML, which could cause problems down the road. I think the preferred solution is to actually remove any options that you wish to hide, and restore them as needed. Using jQuery, you'll only need these 3 functions:

The first function will save the original contents of the *select*. Just to be safe, you may want to call this function when you load the page.

```
function setOriginalSelect ($select) {
    if ($select.data("originalHTML") == undefined) {
        $select.data("originalHTML", $select.html());
    } // If it's already there, don't re-set it
}
```

This next function calls the above function to ensure that the original contents have been saved, and then simply removes the options from the DOM.

```
function removeOptions ($select, $options) {
    setOriginalSelect($select);
    $options.remove();
 }
```

The last function can be used whenever you want to "reset" back to all the original options.

```
function restoreOptions ($select) {
    var ogHTML = $select.data("originalHTML");
    if (ogHTML != undefined) {
        $select.html(ogHTML);
    }
}
```

Note that all these functions expect that you're passing in jQuery elements. For example:

```
// in your search function...
var $s = $('select.someClass');
var $optionsThatDontMatchYourSearch= $s.find('options.someOtherClass');
restoreOptions($s); // Make sure you're working with a full deck
removeOptions($s, $optionsThatDontMatchYourSearch); // remove options not needed
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9CYjy/23/

Comment: @DanBeaulieu There was a function named incorrectly in the previous jsfiddle. I fixed and updated the link above. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Yes, this one was my choice as well. I actually managed to golf the code a bit smaller, by first taking the data value into a variable, if undefined, it will save the options, else it will restore options. My need was specific for such.

Comment: I had to add `var value=$select.val(); $select.html(ogHTML); $select.val(value);` to keep selected value selected even after the restore.

Comment: The cycle of selecting the options to remove and removing them only worked one time. After that, options.remove() had no effect for me. Once I moved the restoreOptions($s) call up a few lines so that I was always working with a full, fresh Select object, it worked.

Answer (score 18):

Ryan P's answer should be changed to:

```
    jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function (show) {
        $(this).toggle(show);
        if (show) {
            if ($(this).parent('span.toggleOption').length)
                $(this).unwrap();
        } else {
            **if ($(this).parent('span.toggleOption').length==0)**
                $(this).wrap('<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />');
        }
    };
```

Otherwise it gets wrapped in too many  tags

Comment: Note that according to the HTML specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element), a `<select>` should only contain `<option>` or `<optgroup>` or script-supporting elements. So you should avoid using invalid `<span>` wrappers.

Answer (score 9):

Select inputs are tricky in this way. What about disabling it instead, this will work cross-browser:

```
$('select').children(':nth-child(even)').prop('disabled', true);
```

This will disable every-other `<option>` element, but you can select which ever one you want.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jYWrH/

Note: If you want to remove the disabled property of an element you can use `.removeProp('disabled')`.

### Update

You could save the `<option>` elements you want to hide in hidden select element:

```
$('#visible').on('change', function () {
    $(this).children().eq(this.selectedIndex).appendTo('#hidden');
});
```

You can then add the `<option>` elements back to the original select element:

```
$('#hidden').children().appendTo('#visible');
```

In these two examples it's expected that the visible select element has the id of `visible` and the hidden select element has the id of `hidden`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jYWrH/1/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in the usage for this answer is the same as `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 9):

The toggleOption function is not perfect and introduced nasty bugs in my application. jQuery will get confused with .val() and .arraySerialize()
Try to select options 4 and 5 to see what I mean:

```
<select id="t">
<option value="v1">options 1</option>
<option value="v2">options 2</option>
<option value="v3" id="o3">options 3</option>
<option value="v4">options 4</option>
<option value="v5">options 5</option>
</select>
<script>
jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};

$("#o3").toggleOption(false); 
$("#t").change(function(e) {
    if($(this).val() != this.value) {
    console.log("Error values not equal", this.value, $(this).val());
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer: You can't. Form elements have very limited styling capabilities.

The best alternative would be to set `disabled=true` on the option (and maybe a gray colour, since only IE does that automatically), and this will make the option unclickable.

Alternatively, if you can, completely remove the `option` element.

Answer (score 7):

```
// Simplest way

var originalContent = $('select').html();

$('select').change(function() {
    $('select').html(originalContent); //Restore Original Content
    $('select option[myfilter=1]').remove(); // Filter my options
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already using JS, you could create a hidden SELECT element on the page, and for each item you are trying to hide in that list, move it to the hidden list. This way, they can be easily restored.

I don't know a way offhand of doing it in pure CSS... I would have thought that the display:none trick would have worked.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `option[value=your-value]{display:none;}`

This works fine in Chrome, at least in 2022, as well as in safari and FF.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove them from the `<select>` using JavaScript. That is the only guaranteed way to make them go away.

Comment: Using jQuery, this can be done with remove: `$('options').remove();`

Answer (score 2):

!!! WARNING !!!

Replace the second "IF" by "WHILE" or doesn't work !

```
jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        while( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

this one seems to work for me in chrome

```
$("#selectid span option").unwrap();
$("#selectid option:not([filterattr=filtervalue])").wrap('<span/>');
```

Comment: Please add code format to your code, either by indenting with 4 spaces or wrapping your code with `.

Comment: this code is great! it works on latest chrome, firefox and IE 11, that's good enough for me :)

Comment: prior to my last comment, this thing works on IE 7 too! so ff 3.5, this is what I came up with at the last, it somehow on IE and chrome preserve the value that has been selected before options get hidden and if another value doesn't set after bringing back the options browser will set the option selected as before!

Answer (score 1):

Modern solution is simply apply CSS hidden like:

```html
<option value="" style="display:none;">Select Item</option>
```

Or with a class

```html
<option value="" class="hidden">Please select</option>
```

---

Note in class case, add css like

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but most of these seem quite complicated.

Here's how I did it:

```
var originalSelect = $('#select-2').html();

// filter select-2 on select-1 change
$('#select-1').change(function (e) {

    var selected = $(this).val();

    // reset select ready for filtering
    $('#select-2').html(originalCourseSelect);

    if (selected) {
        // filter
        $('#select-2 option').not('.t' + selected).remove();
    }

});
```

markup of select-1:

```
<select id='select-1'>
<option value=''>Please select</option>
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
```

markup of select-2:

```
<select id='select-2'>
<option class='t1'>One</option>
<option class='t2'>Two</option>
<option>Always visible</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, this can achieved by **HTML** too.

```html
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose</option>
    <option value="0">hii</option>
    <option value="1">hello</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022 Answer Summary And Cross-Browser Solution**

Currently, these methods **do not** work on Safari:

- visibility: hidden
- display: block
- hidden attribute

So none of proposed solutions here using these methods works on Safari, so they can not be accepted.

**Solution**

The solution is to keep special options in an array, and hide/restore them on-demand. For example to show/hide day selection based on year/month selection:

When you initialize your component:

```
const tailDayOptions = [];

  const saveTailDayOptions = () => {
    const daySelector = document.querySelector('#daySelector');
    for (let day = 29; day <= 31; day++) {
      tailDayOptions[day - 1] = daySelector.querySelector(`option[value='${day - 1}']`);
    }
  }
```

When a user changes year or month:

```
for (let day = 29; day <= 31; day++) {
      if (day <= daysInMonth) {
        daySelector.appendChild(tailDayOptions[day - 1])
      } else {
        const dayOption = daySelector.querySelector(`option[value='${day - 1}']`);
        if (dayOption) {
          daySelector.removeChild(dayOption);
        }
      }
    }
```

**How does it work**

1. It saves options for day 29,30 and 31 to a tailDayOptions array
2. When user changes the year or month, daysInMonth are calculated
3. If a given day (e.g. 29th) is not present in a given year-month and it is available in the select options, it gets removed from there
4. If a given day is available in a given year-month it gets re-added to the select from the tailDayOptions array

**Compatibility**

Compatible with Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Should be compatible with all other browsers.