# How to remove/hide select options from select-list

Tags: javascript, select, hide

I've got a select list like this:

```
<select id="selectlist" name="selectproduct" >
    <option value=""> --- Select product  --- </option>
    <option value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3">Product 3</option>
    <option value="4">Product 4</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately I can't edit it.
Is there any method which let me hide the "Product 4" option by default?
I'm trying with CSS, but it doesn't work with IE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24516786

Answer (score 10):

To hide it, wrap it with a span tag.

```
$( "#selectlist option[value=4]" ).wrap( "<span>" );
```

To show it, unwrap the span tag if it has one.

```
if ( $( "#selectlist option[value=4]" ).parent().is( "span" ) ){
    $( "#selectlist option[value=4]" ).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: That would create illegal HTML

Comment: I don't think "illegal" and "solution" have any relation or the world might look a lot different. But this might be an easier way to unwrap: $( "#selectlist span > option[value=4]" ).unwrap();

Answer (score 5):

using css to hide options is not supported in IE, so you need to update the `option`s list itself.

Try something like

```
$('#selectlist option[value=4]').remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p8Gmm/2/)

or if you want to enable it later

```
var sel = $('#selectlist');
var opts = sel.find('option');

$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    sel.empty().append(this.checked ? opts : opts.filter('[value!=4]'));
}).click()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p8Gmm/)

Comment: Don't know why, but it doesen't work...
I'm using the JQuery no.conflict method, but nothing...

Comment: @user2132234 if you are using noConflict then instead of `$` use `jQuery`

Comment: I'm using
var $nol = jQuery.noConflict();
and change "$" with "$nol" in your function, is it the correct way?

Comment: @user2132234 yes it is

Comment: Here's the web url:
http://provagas1860.opentur.it/destinazioni
THe select list is on the right!

Comment: you have a js error fix it first `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null `

Comment: also where is the script added

Answer (score 5):

You can hide option using following line include in scripting.

```
    $("#selectlist option[value='4']").hide();
```

And if you want to again show this option use following line.

```
   $("#selectlist option[value='4']").show();
```

Answer (score 3):

## To save your time, please read the following answer.

OK, I searched for a few hours and I noticed that there is **NO WORKING WAY** to "hide" (what I mean is make the option temporally disappeared from the drop-down list) for all browsers, such as set the visibility to be hidden or style="display: none".

My final approach is: 
 1. Create an array to store all the options for the dropdown list.
 2. Use a method to dynamically update the drop-down list according what you want to be shown.

That's it, if you want to use a drop down list without using any library

Answer (score 1):

You can "hide" the option by moving it to a hidden select element or cached document fragment, then move it back when you want to show it:

```
var selectTool = (function() {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  return {
    hideOpt: function (selectId, optIndex) {
      var sel = document.getElementById(selectId);
      var opt = sel && sel[optIndex];
      console.log(opt);

      if (opt) {
        frag.appendChild(opt);
      }
    },

    showOpt: function (selectId) {
      var sel = document.getElementById(selectId);
      var opt = frag.firstChild;
      if (sel && opt) {
        sel.appendChild(opt);
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

Then you can hide the 4th option like:

```
<input type="button" value="Hide option" onclick="
  selectTool.hideOpt('selectlist',4);
">
```

and show it again using:

```
<input type="button" value="Show option" onclick="
  selectTool.showOpt('selectlist');
">
```

All play code of course, but you should get some ideas. If you want to store many options, you'll need a way of referencing them so maybe store them in an object with some form of referencing scheme.

Comment: ? I need only to hide, I'm not interested to show options by clicking anywhere

Comment: Fine, the above "hides" the option. If you don't need to show it again, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable that option with disabled attribute.

```
<select id="selectlist" name="selectproduct" >
 <option value=""> --- Select product  --- </option>
 <option value="1">Product 1</option>
 <option value="2">Product 2</option>
 <option value="3">Product 3</option>
 <option value="4" disabled="disabled">Product 4</option>
</select>
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/vhKdw/)

Comment: Disabling an option doesn't hide it, it just makes it not selectable. And the disabled attribute doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

see this link

http://jsfiddle.net/DKKMN/

```
<select id="selectlist" name="selectproduct" >
 <option value=""> --- Select product  --- </option>
 <option value="1">Product 1</option>
 <option value="2">Product 2</option>
 <option value="3">Product 3</option>
 <option value="4" id="i">Product 4</option>
</select>


#i{display:none;}
```

create an id and in style make it invisble

Comment: This solution does not hide the option in IE11.

Comment: Yeah, always ask yourself "This works, but what happens when Microsoft"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using JQuery as well.

```
$("#selectlist option[value='option4']").remove();
```

Comment: no errors, it simply shows the options like it have not any javascript script loaded

Comment: You are messing something up. Try doing it with in-line script instead. This is the way. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

to append the child below the list of option using java script.

```
`var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.text = "All Users";
 option.value = "all_user";
 var select = document.getElementById("log_user_type");
 select.appendChild(option);`
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove some option from select list you can use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function() {    
        $('#select_list_id option[value="AB"],option[value="SK"]').remove();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<option value="4" style="display:none">Product 4</option>
```

hides the 4th option by default.

Comment: [insert programming meme here]