# Select box with some hidden options not showing any options

Tags: jquery, html, dom, user-interface

[Example of this issue on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUSn9/)

Ran in Chrome, latest, Ubuntu.

When using jQuery to hide `option` elements inside a `select` element it uses `display: none;` and `display: inline` to alter visibility. I have encountered a situation where when a majority of `option` elements have been hidden, those that should be visible do not appear either. Removing one option from the list at this point will show just one other option but with arrow buttons, as if the issue is with the height of the `select` drop down.

I have been unable to find whether there is a limit placed on the number of hidden options inside a select or similar restrictions; has anyone encountered this before?

**Examples**

- [Hide/show class example](http://jsfiddle.net/XUSn9/5/) showing how it works when one block is commented out
- [Two block CSS example](http://jsfiddle.net/XUSn9/6/) to show how one set of options works, another doesn't.

Comment: I can't really see a problem in that fiddle.  It also seems that all the options are `display: none`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Comment: I see the problem (@ExplosionPills - the incl ones are at bottom), and it appears related to the `price-3` class (delete those and it seems to work: [Revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUSn9/5/). Haven't figured out why just yet.

Comment: The fiddle took code directly from the app, just to try and stay true to life. I maybe could have explained it better. Interesting with the removal of classes; definitely seems like a limit on how many items can be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage jQuery to add or remove the `<option />` element. The class and style attributes are not supported across all browsers, [See W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html). Not sure how you're handing down or evaluating the data but this is a down and dirty way:

```
$('select[name="price"] option[value="whatever"]').remove();
$('select[name="price"]').append(($('<option>', { value : key }).text(value));
```