# display:none doesn't work for option

Tags: html, css

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wener/WC9yy/)

HTML:

```
display:none <b>not works</b>,the hidden can <b>not select</b>.<br>
<select size="5">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="H">H</option>
    <option value="I">I</option>
</select><br>

display:none <b>works</b>,the hidden <b>can select</b>.<br>
<select>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="H">H</option>
    <option value="I">I</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select{width:50px;}

[value=C]{
    display: none;
}
/* will hold the position */ 
[value=B]{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The size attribute will affect the display and visibility, what happen to this ?

How can I hide the option in select which has a `size` attribute ?

Comment: I cannot select the hidden item in either sample. Why do you have an option there in the first place if you don't need it? Just omit it from the list

Comment: You can't set `display` to an option field in Chrome and IE. --> http://glidingphenomena.blogspot.ch/2010/06/styledisplaynone-doesnt-work-on-option.html

Comment: @dTDesign But it works under chrome, if the select do not have size attribute. I want to show the match results use the origin select, and do not use DOM op.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**See updated section**

I think you can not do that only with CSS for all browsers you'll need some JS code, there is a previous question quite similar:

[How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)

In Chrome (v. 30) "display:none" doesn't work, however in Firefox (v. 24) It works, the option with "display:none" doesn't appear in the list.

**UPDATE2:**

In the current Chrome (v. 70) an Firefox (v. 63) versions, the use of css with "display:none" along with attribute "disabled" in the option tag removes the option from the list and it doesn't appear any more.

```
<html><body>
    <select>
      <option disabled style="display:none">Hola</option>
      <option>Hello</option>
      <option>Ciao</option>
    </select>
</body></html>
```

Thanks to @achecopar for the help

Comment: The option "Hola" would also be accesible through the keyboard (arrows and typing) even if it is not the first in the list. Chrome v71. I found using both display:none and the disabled attribute works though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't got a Safari browser to test/fix it. If you find out a fix, I can update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique for hiding options within a select in this post: [How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

The property `Display:none` wont work on the options tag
so you have only two options as work around

```
1. Either disable then with disabled="disabled".
2. Remove the options you don't want to see and insert them again when needed.
```

you may be able to find some other work around too, but i don't think it will be consistent in all the browsers

Answer (score 0):

Use following jQuery to hide and show  under select

```
jQuery(selector).toggleOption(true); // show option
jQuery(selector).toggleOption(false); // hide option
```

Comment: I don't see anyone talking about jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

is you need this...

```
<select>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option disabled value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option disabled value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="H">H</option>
    <option value="I">I</option>
</select>
```

the disable value are not select-able.

if you want to hide go here..

http://jsbin.com/anoci