# jQuery - hide option element by value

Tags: jquery, select, hide, html-select

Trying to hide an option element from a list. I have tried several methods however, cannot seems to work.
I need to call select by name as I cannot add ID or class.

```
$('select[name*="boxes"] option[value="box6"]').hide();
```

here the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q2nb08t6/

any suggestions?

Comment: `hide()` does add the style `display:none;` to your element. But this style as no effect on options. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270386/displaynone-not-works-for-option

Comment: Ahh--it is different for different browsers. Works fine in chrome and FF, but not in safari or IE

Comment: @Ted yep can confirm it does not works at all in my safari v8.0.6

Comment: Is there any way to make the code working in all browsers ?

Comment: Not if you just want to hide. Removing is an option as @Ted pointed in his answer but will force you to recreate the dom element if you need to reshow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can go with removing it, this seems to work in all browsers:

```
$('select[name*="boxes"] option[value="box6"]').remove();
```

Tested in FF, Chrome, Safari, IE and Opera.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2nb08t6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to

```
$('select[name*="boxes"] > option[value="box6"]').hide();
```

The `>` means to search the preceding selector for the following selector.

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2nb08t6/2/

Also, if this is a one-off situation, you could simplify your selector even further to:

```
$('option[value="box6"]').hide();
```

Comment: This is a browser compatibility issue -- see the link posted in the comments by @b.enoit.be : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270386/displaynone-not-works-for-option