# jquery functions are not working in safari but working properly in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am working on the following code. I want to show only option elements depending on the first selected value. As this code is working properly in chrome but not in safari.
the `hide()` and `show()` functions are not working. How i can improve this code so that it will work in safari also?
my html code is as follows:

```
<body>
<select id="shopcategory">
    <option></option>
    <option value="american" selected="selected">american</option>
    <option value="indian">indian</option>
    <option value="chinese">chinese</option>
</select>
<select id="shop-ar">
    <option class="american">1</option>
    <option class="american">2</option>
    <option class="american">3</option>
    <option class="indian">4</option>
    <option class="indian">5</option>
    <option class="indian">6</option>
    <option class="chinese">7</option>
    <option class="chinese">8</option>
    <option class="chinese">9</option>
</select>
```

my jquery code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
    $("#shopcategory").change(function(){
        select= $("#shopcategory option:selected").attr("value");
        $("#shop-ar").children().each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("class")== select){
        //  only selected category options must be displayed  
                $(this).show();
            }
            else{
                $(this).hide();
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: why are you using `attr("value")` and not `.val()`

Comment: So what part is not working? Simple console.log lines will see what is different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762709/jquery-hide-option-element-by-value

Comment: the code works properly except hide()..but when i use remove() or empty() instead of hide()..these functions are working properly..

Comment: Because options can not be hidden with CSS in those browser. So you need to remove it.

Comment: hi sir, with some changes i was able to use hide() show() functions..but i don't know  why it is working now and love to know more about  this browser compatibility solutions..thank you for your intrest !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again and this time i got desired solution which is as follows:sorry for not formatting it correctly..here is my html:

```
 <select name="shopcategory" id="shopcategory">
   <option  value="all" selected disabled="disabled">cuisane</option>
   <option  value="american">american</option>
   <option  value="indian">indian</option>
   <option  value="chinese">chinese</option>
</select>
<select name="shop-ar" id="shop-ar" >
  <option class="button" selected="selected">All</option>
  <option data-val="american" value="beverly-hills" >Beverly Hil</option>
  <option data-val="american" value="santa-monica" >Santa </option>
  <option data-val="indian" value="hialea" >Hia</option>
  <option data-val="indian" value="little-havana">Little </option>
  <option data-val="indian" value="north-miami">North </option>
  <option data-val="indian" value="south-beach">South </option>
  <option data-val="chinese" value="chelsea">Chel</option>
  <option data-val="chinese" value="harlem">Har</option>
  <option data-val="chinese" value="noho">No</option>
  <option data-val="chinese" value="soho">So</option>
</select>
```

jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){                  
         var select_clone = $('#shop-ar option');
         $('#shopcategory').change(function() {
         $("option").show();
         $('#shop-ar').html(select_clone.filter('[data-val="' + this.value + '"]')).show();
         $("#shop-ar").prepend("<option value='' disabled='disabled'>Restaurants</option>").val('');
```

})
})

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
$("#shopcategory").change(function(){

var select = $("#shopcategory option:selected").attr("value");
// alert(select);

$("#shop-ar").children().each(function(){
    //$(".american").hide();
    // alert($(this).attr("id"));
    if($(this).attr("class") == select){
        $(this).append();
    }
    else{
        $(this).detach();
    }
   });
 });
});
```

You can use .append() and .detach() functions at the place of .show() and .hide() functions as they will work better with safari and other browsers.

Comment: rather that pasting code you should first point out the problem in the OP and then suggest the code , and you should properly format your post for readability

Comment: thanks for your advice sir...i'll follow your instructions next time  !!

Comment: if my post helped to you to solve your problem then please approve my answer.

Comment: actually sir, your code is not what i am looking for..but surely, that helped me..thank you !!