# Hiding Option tags in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Let me start off saying I hate IE.

I have a bit of code running to hide options in a select tag and then narrow them down and only show the narrowed down options. This works perfectly everywhere, except I.E. and I'm not really sure why.

My code looks something like this...

```js
$("select[name='FormId']").prop("disabled", false);

$(".modalContent select[name='FormId'] option").hide();

var formIds = this.model.collection.models.map(function ( model ) {
    return model.attributes.Form.attributes.Id
});

formIds.forEach(function ( formId ) {
    $(".modalContent select[name='FormId'] option[value='"+ formId +"']").show();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Comment: Sorry to hear that you hate IE; we're working hard to make up for the past. I'll file this difference with Chrome/Firefox as an Interop bug and have our team look at it a.s.a.p.

Comment: @Blazemonger I already looked at that thread, and I can't use what they suggested. I can't start with an empty select because of how I'm populating them.

Comment: @zazvorniki Can you store the option elements in a `documentFragment` or array, and simply add/remove to the `select` as needed?

Answer (score 0):

`this.model.collection.models` is a plain array, so you'd need ES5 for `map` to work on it. just use `this.model.collection.map` which will use the safe one from underscore

Comment: This is stop ie from showing my options?

Comment: probably not, check the duplicate for that (personally I would just gray them out with `disabled`).
this won't make your code work at all in <IE9 tho

Comment: I can't use what the other threads workaround. I have to be able to hide my options some way or another.

Comment: @zazvorniki why don't you just remove the `option`s?

Comment: Believe me, I tried. But I can't because they are coming in from the database and are different for each place this drop down appears. It's very dynamic.

Comment: @zazvorniki well you can't hide it, it's a dead end. I would think of using the backbone methods like `collection.filter` and others to rebuild the select, there has to be another solution.