# Wrong display of Select Option Tag in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have got very long list of `options` in `select`.

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    ...
    <option value='100'>100</option>
    <option value='101'>101</option>
    ...
    <option value='200'>200</option>
    <option value='201'>201</option>
</select>
```

Everything is OK on Firefox and Chrome.

But when I want to hide by js some options and leave displayed only few:

```
<select>
    <option value='1' style='display:none'>1</option>
    <option value='2' style='display:none'>2</option>
    ...
    <option value='100' style='display:none'>100</option>
    <option value='101'>101</option>
    <option value='102'>102</option>
    <option value='103'>103</option>
    <option value='104' style='display:none'>104</option>
    ...
    <option value='200' style='display:none'>200</option>
    <option value='201' style='display:none'>201</option>
</select>
```

On Firefox still everything is OK - I see only few options very well.
But on Chrome - something is wrong. I see nothing (it looks like menu with zero height) or menu is too small (if i want to display little more options - i see only 1 or 2 (little % of displayed options) with scrollbar)

What happened?

Comment: Can you provide the code that used for hiding options?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9234830/2126792

Comment: You should use js to regenrate the options by using a for loop on the options you need and set the html value of the select box.  The display:none on sub-levels can be buggy .

Comment: Dear, Could you give use a bit more informations? On [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j64j0s7s/) it works for me on both Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: code to hide option is simple: $('someSelector').css('display','none');