# show/hide options in drop down using jquery

Tags: jquery, dropdownbox

I have two `drop down boxes`.

```
<select id="brand">
<option id="20">Honda</option>
<option id="22">Maruti</option>
</select>

<select id="model">
<option id="50">City</option>
<option id="51">Alto</option>
<option id="52">Amaze</option>
<option id="53">Civic</option>
<option id="54">Swift</option>
<option id="55">Ritz</option>
</select>
```

Depending on the `brand` selected I have to load the `model` drop down with appropriated values. If user select `Honda` from `brand` then the `model` drop down should only contain(display) `City, Amaze,` and `Civic` values.

Since the `option id are dynamically created` I can't access the option via its id.There is no need to add new options, because all options are there. So I only need to `show/hide options in model drop down.`

I am confused because I can't access the option via its id(they are dynamically created), I can only access by its text.

How can I do this?? Please help me...

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, this is invalid HTML markup. Use instead `data-*` attribute, e.g, `data-id`. But then, if you want to target specifically `Alto` option, how would you avoid to target `Ritz` too? That's not clear! So reading your question again, use a `data-model` common for each car model and filter using that

Comment: this will help you . you need to add span as parent of options then it will work on IE.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Comment: @A.Wolff  yes you are rite . i just suggest if want to hide options then it will not work in IE browser.  we need to use invalid HTML for IE browser. you suggestion correct .

Comment: Somehow, somewhere on the server, hopefully in a database, you have some kind of relationship between the brand(s) and the model(s). Therefore it would be wise to create a script returning a model list when it's given a brand name or id, and then use AJAX to call that script and rebuild the models list each time a change occurs in the brand dropdown (user selects another brand). If you don't want to use AJAX, I would suggest to populate the models dropdown with all models but add a a data-attribute linking it to the brand, allowing you to target it with a CSS selector.

Comment: sorry its a typo, id is unique...changed

Answer (score 3):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/kh0anm1s/)

```
$('#brand').change(function() {    
    var brandValue = $(this).val();
    if(brandValue == "Honda") {
        $("#model option[id='50']").show();        
    }        
})
```

Comment: I can't use id of options because id is dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

if your select ID is static always you can:

```
$("#model").find("option[id='50']").hide();
```

However you shouldn't has multiple Id. use another attribute instead of it.

Comment: option id are dynamically created

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in order to get the content of the options :

```
// When the selected value of brand changes
$('#brand').change(function(){
    // Loop through each option from model
    $('#model option').each(function(){
        // If you chose Honda
        if ($('#brand option:selected').text() == 'Honda')
        {
            // If the option is City, Amaze or Civic, show it
            if ($.inArray($(this).text(), ['City', 'Amaze', 'Civic']))
                $(this).show();
            // If not, hide it
            else
                $(this).hide();
        }
        // You chose Maruti
        else
        {
            // You didn't specify what to do in this case si I guess you want to show all
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Be careful, you have the same id several times in the code (50 and 51). This is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `hide()` and `show()` functions to achieve the same.

Below is the code block for your reference.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select[Title='Status']").find('option:contains("Open")').hide();         
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hondaModels = [
  "City",
  "Amaze",
  "Civic"
];

var marutiModels = [
  "Alto",
  "Swift",
  "Ritz"
];

var updateModelList = function(){
  $("#model").find("option").hide();
  var model = $("#brand").val().toLowerCase();
  switch(model){
    case "honda" :
      hondaModels.forEach(function(model){
        $("#model").find("option:contains(" +model +")").show();
      });
      $("#model").val("City");
      break;
    case "maruti" :
       marutiModels.forEach(function(model){
        $("#model").find("option:contains(" +model +")").show();
      });
      $("#model").val("Alto");
      break;
    default : 
     return false;
  }
  
};

updateModelList();

$("#brand").on("change", function(){
  updateModelList();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="brand">
    <option id="20">Honda</option>
    <option id="22">Maruti</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="model">
    <option id="50">City</option>
    <option id="51">Alto</option>
    <option id="50">Amaze</option>
    <option id="51">Civic</option>
    <option id="50">Swift</option>
    <option id="51">Ritz</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I search for text nodes of option and show them using array to stores models for particular brand.