# Identical Select menus list item toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop a feature which involves 2 select list items.

Flow goes something like this,

1. There are two list items (identical) with the same list items
2. When I select an option from `Main Tags` list, the same option in `Sub Tags` list should get disabled. For example, If I select `Tag 1` from the `Main Tags` list then `Tag 1` from the `Sub Tags` list should get disabled. (Toggle effect: when I select other options from the 1st list, then previously disabled item should b enabled)
3. `Sub Tags` list is multiple selection. Here selected values gets displad nex to it as a tags with delete tag option on it (Which is working in my code). But When user change the option from `Main Tags` list and the same thing is already been displayed here as a `Selected tags` section then it should get removed from `selected tags` section and `Sub Tags` list (Which is disable at this point) as well.

**Basic idea is not to have same option under both `Main Tags` and `Sub Tags`**

Hope my question is clear.

Here is my current code,

```
$(function () {
    $("#tagSel").change(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $("#tags").append('<span id="' + $this.val() + '"> ' + $this.find('option:selected').text() + ' <a href="#">&times;</a></span>');
        $this.find('option:selected').prop("disabled", true);
    });
    $("#tags").on("click", "span a", function () {
        $("#tagSel option[value='" + $(this).parent().attr("id") + "']").prop('disabled',null);
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#tagSel_main").append('<i ></i>')
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4ktduf39/11/)**

Comment: what should happen if user select `Tag 2` from `Sub Tags` first. Should this option be disabled in `Main Tags`?

Comment: Should the option be removed from `sub tags` on selection?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it should work exactly this way https://jsfiddle.net/4ktduf39/28/ ... but this is not working as expected in IE, in chrome it works perfect.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao IE 11

Comment: @Sowmya check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ktduf39/36/)** Not sure whether it is completely correct or not.. But works 75% in IE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this might do the trick.

I've commented the function to clarify how if functions.

```
$('#tagSel_main').on('change', function() {
    /* find selected option */
    var selector = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    /* remove the disabled property from the active sub tag (if it exists) */
    $('.activeSubTag').removeClass('activeSubTag').prop('disabled', false );
    /* disable the now selected sub tag and give a class (for the above rule) */
    $('#tagSel option[value='+selector+']').addClass('activeSubTag').prop('disabled', true );
    /* remove the sub tag from "selected sub tags" (if it exists) */
    $('#tags span#'+selector).remove();
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4ktduf39/17/)

## EDIT

It seemed that IE and Chrome don't allow `display:none` on an option. Therefor I found [this workaround on SO]]([How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)).

Code therefor changes to:

```
 $('#tagSel_main').on('change', function() {
    var selector = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    $('.activeSubTag option').unwrap();
    $('#tagSel option[value='+selector+']').wrap('<span class="activeSubTag" style="display:none"></span>');
    $('#tags span#'+selector).remove();
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4ktduf39/30/)

Comment: People, please... I really don't mind a downvote. But an explanation would be nice. I believe my solution is good and works, so what's wrong with it :)

Comment: Hey Thank you.. As I saw the Danyial answer first, I assumed taht it was answerd by him..  Not sure y is this downvote.. I am gonna upvote it.. Could u pls help with additional thing about add/remove instead of disable enable?

Comment: is it possible to do Remove/Add toggle instead of Disable/Enable in 2nd select list while selecting the Sub tags?

Comment: @Sowmya 
You mean that the option isn't visible at all in the 2nd list? If so, check jsfiddle.net/4ktduf39/26

Comment: Thank you.. Thats all I wanted... I merged ur previous 2 fiddle and this is my expected answer [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4ktduf39/28/)

Comment: but in updated fiddle, when you delete the selected tags, it is not adding it back to Sub tags list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like this :

```
$("#tagSel_main").change(function () {
    var mainSel = $(this);

    $("#tagSel option").prop('disabled',null);
    $( "#" + mainSel.val() ).remove();
    $("#tagSel option[value='" + mainSel.val() + "']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("span").each( function() {
        $("#tagSel option[value='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").prop("disabled", true);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/4ktduf39/16/)

```js
$(function () {
 $("#tagSel").change(function () {
  $this = $(this);
  $("#tags").append('<span id="' + $this.val() + '"> ' + $this.find('option:selected').text() + ' <a href="#">&times;</a></span>');
  $this.find('option:selected').prop("disabled", true);
 });
 $("#tags").on("click", "span a", function () {
  $("#tagSel option[value='" + $(this).parent().attr("id") + "']").prop('disabled',null);
  $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#tagSel_main").append('<i ></i>')
 });
});

var currentMainTag = $('#tagSel_main').val(); 
$('#tagSel_main').change(function(){
    $('#tagSel option[value="'+currentMainTag+'"]').prop("disabled", false);
    currentMainTag = $(this).val(); 
    var textSe = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

 $('#tagSel option[value="'+currentMainTag+'"]').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```css
* {  font-family: 'Segoe UI';  font-size: 10pt;}
body > div{  display:inline-block; width:20%; vertical-align:top ;  height:100px;  background-color: bisque;  padding: 10px;}
.sub_tags{display:inline-block; width:60%;     background-color: bisque; padding: 10px;}
.sub_tags > div {width:40%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top}
.tags {   display:inline-block;   width:100%}
.tags p {  margin: 0;}
.tags span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 9px;
  background: #E4E4E4;
  border: solid 1px #A0A054;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin:5px 
}
.tags span a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>Main Tag:</span><br/>
<select id="tagSel_main">
  <option value="tag1">Tag 1</option>
  <option value="tag2">Tag 2</option>
  <option value="tag3">Tag 3</option>
  <option value="tag4">Tag 4</option>
  <option value="tag5">Tag 5</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="sub_tags">
<div>
<span>Sub Tag:</span><br/>
<select id="tagSel" multiple>
  <option value="tag1">Tag 1</option>
  <option value="tag2">Tag 2</option>
  <option value="tag3">Tag 3</option>
  <option value="tag4">Tag 4</option>
  <option value="tag5">Tag 5</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
    Selected Sub Tags:<br/>
<div class="tags">
  <p id="tags"></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply Add This Changes

```
$("#tagSel_main").change(function () {
    $("#tagSel option").each(function(){
    if($this.val()==$(this).val()){
     $(this).prop("disabled", true);
     }else{
     $(this).prop("disabled", false);
}});
```

See Fiddler Update

https://jsfiddle.net/kubkzytz/

Comment: SyntaxError in your fiddle

Comment: This alomost worket but while deleting the Selected sub tags, is it possible to do `Remove/Add` toggle instead of `Disable/Enable` in 2nd select list?

Comment: Euhm... https://jsfiddle.net/kubkzytz/ links to a Fiddle with my code in it, and not your solution??