# Option tag display block/none in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

This is an additional problem to my **[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840067/identical-select-menus-list-item-toggle)**.

I have a perfect code (**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ozas9wh9/)**) which works as expected. But this works fine in Chrome and firefox but not in **Internet Explorer**. That is bcause IE doesn't support `disply: none/block` for option tags.

To explain the flow of the functionality,

- Main Tag and Sub Tag are 2 different section which has the same list values
- same item should not be present in the both section. When User select `Item 1` from `Main tag`, same item should be removed from the `Sub Tag` list.
- `Sub Tag` has a section called `Selected sub Tags`,  where in selected sub tags will be shown as tags. When we delete these selected tags, it should display back in `Sub Tag` list
- If user select different item (example: `Item 2`) in `Main tag` list, it should toggle the `remove/add` in `Sub Tag` list. Means, remove the currently selected item (`Item 2`) and add back the previously removed item (`Item 1`) to `Sub Tag`. If the Item 2 is already selected in Selected Sub Tags list, it should get removed from `Selected Sub Tags` list as well

**All I need is to get the given code work in Internet Explorer.**

**Or is there any way to get the same funtionality with `ul li` instead of list item ?**

Comment: Hiding an option is not a cross browser thingy. You may have to look at other options such as disabling/removing options while keeping track of what's been removed, so that, you can add them later.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unsemantic to just hide an option. There's some browser (Internet Explorer in your case) which can't do that. Your best shot to handle all browsers is to actually remove the option from the DOM, just not hiding it.

Do you want something fun with your demo ? Select `Tag 1` as the main tag. Then select `Tag 2` as a sub tag. Now play with UP and DOWN arrow on your keboard and feel the magic. So now, can you really say that is a perfect code which works as expected ?

If you want to have a working code, you have to remove and add options in the select. Hiding an option is too weird and not really supported by browsers (even firefox and chrome).