# css - select option won't show up using display block

Tags: html, css, select

I have a select tag with options in it, using css I've made them all display none, except one (the very last one) I've made it display block, but it won't show up, is it because there is a lot of options?

```
<select>
     <option>example1</option>
     <option>example2</option>
     <option>example3</option>
</select>
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/rkh4gtzr/)

### Update

when I reduce options it works fine, Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/96x18fpL/)

Comment: Post your css as well please. I have a feeling your display:none is affecting them all.

Comment: It shows up in Chrome. You could use the !important at the end to overwrite the original css.

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel nonsense, as inline always trumps external anyway the `!important` will do nothing. Also, in my Chrome the last item is showing up fine. TS likely sees a browser bug resulting from a dropdown with 2000 items.

Comment: You cant give options styles, look here: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)

Comment: Using `display` on an option is non-standard and browsers will react in different ways to it. When I try it, it works as you expect in Firefox, but Chrome shows no items and IE shows all items.

Comment: @VikingBlooded see the example! all the css is in there, and the problem is also. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rkh4gtzr/2/)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes That's what am thinking too, but it's important for me to have a lot of options.

Comment: Then why are you hiding all of them? (hint: you have a [huge XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes because I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Options can't have styles according w3c standart. You can change color and background only.
Select may contains only 999 options. You can delete some extra options and left 999 and it will be works.

Comment: Please point me to the part of the standards that states this?

Comment: [Oh wait `display` does apply to *All Elements* according to current CSS standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Comment: I cann't find it right now, but i had some problem one month ago. I have decided this problem with javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: @TarasPetrivskyi then why when I reduce options it works fine? See the question update!

Comment: That's different. You talked about the standards, and they don't prohibit any styling on `option` elements. The problem is just that most styles are either highly impractical in select options (`transform:rotate`?), or flat out impossible if the browser uses OS-native widgets. You can, depending on the UA, also have luck with margins/paddings and fonts.

Comment: It's an interestin situation.... I think you had better use JS. Sorry, but a can not help you.

Comment: I've tried chrome, FF, Safari, IE, none of them are working for this.

Comment: Select may contains only 999 options. You can delete some extra options and left 999 and it will be works.