# How to insert a var inside JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert the var "id" where "SP" is located. Is it possible?

```
var id = $(this).val();
    $("#select2").children("option[value^='SP_']").show();
```

The whole code above:

(I'm trying to do this because I'll add another select (#select3) that will need the _1, _2, _3 filter that I'm using on option values.)

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="vazio">Selecione um Estado</option>
  <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
  <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option value="vazio">Selecione uma Cidade</option>
  <option value="SP_1">Cidade São Paulo</option>
  <option value="SP_2">Cidade São Paulo</option>
  <option value="SP_3">Cidade São Paulo</option>
  <option value="PE_1">Cidade Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="PE_2">Cidade Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="PE_3">Cidade Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="GO_1">Cidade Goiás</option>
  <option value="GO_2">Cidade Goiás</option>
  <option value="BA_1">Cidade Bahia<option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select2").children("option").hide();
});
$("#select1").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#select2").children("option").hide();
    $("#select2").children("option[value^='SP_']").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking if this is at all possible or how to do this safely (ie, not to confuse the selector)?

Comment: I'll add more of my code so you can understand what I'm trying to do. If you have a better solution, so I don't need to confuse the selector, please share with me.

Comment: It's a basic string concatenation. `"option[value^='" + id + "_']"`

Comment: I feel stupid right now. I'm still learning, haha. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Note that hiding and showing `<option>` elements doesn't work in IE. There are some [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css) about that with possible workarounds/solutions.

Comment: @nnnnnn what if the value matches `/['\[\]]/` or other "bad" characters?

Comment: @XerenNarcy - It won't. The value is coming from the options in a select element.

Comment: @nnnnnn but you don't know that :) it's just what's shown here and it could be a simplified case.

Comment: @XerenNarcy - I do know that. I'm psychic.

Comment: @AndréMartins it may be tedious and repetitive but if it works - use a separate `<select>` for each subcategory. eg, one for `SP` another for `PE` and so on, and switch display of the selects. Otherwise (and I don't know this would work) you may need to actually add / remove `<option>` to the select.

Comment: @AndréMartins there's many many ways. You could hide `<select>` blocks that have the pre-filtered `<option>`, you could (since you're using jQuery) use a [UI widget for selects](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) which are more versatile and cross-browser friendly...

Comment: Check the answers to the question I linked to above for several different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

See if it works

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qPvVZTSqilzPmUt3MDGx?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <select id='mySelectBox'>
    <option value='SP_1'>test Val</option>
    <option value='UG_1'>test Val</option>
    <option value='SP_2'>test Val</option>
    <option value='UG_1'>test Val</option>
    <option value='SP_3'>test Val</option>
  </select>
<script>
  var myOpts = document.getElementById('mySelectBox').options;
  for(var i=0; i<myOpts.length; i++) {
    if(myOpts[i].value.indexOf('SP') > -1)
        myOpts[i].setAttribute('id', 'myId_' + i);
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Result**

```
<select id="mySelectBox">
    <option value="SP_1" id="myId_0">test Val</option>
    <option value="UG_1">test Val</option>
    <option value="SP_2" id="myId_2">test Val</option>
    <option value="UG_1">test Val</option>
    <option value="SP_3" id="myId_4">test Val</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I wrote this code, only top three lines of this question were written and the question was `I want to insert the var "id" where "SP" is located. Is it possible?`. So it's all according to that.:)

 http://www.stackoverflow.com/posts/38387702/revisions#rev15da5f7d-0a2c-41c6-a64e-9c8c27adc24b

Comment: As you said in your comment, it was quite simple string concatenation. So I guess I mis-interpreted the question :)

Comment: Oh well. We've all done that. I'll remove my other comments now that you've seen them.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
            $("<select id='select3'><option></option></select>").appendTo("body");
               var id = 1;
               $("#select3").children().attr({id:"SP_" + id}).text("SP_" + id);

           });
</script>
```