# hiding option elements in css for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a web application. There were two classes A & B. In A I have few elements. The task is when I drag the elements from A to B. The Elements dragged should be shown in B and they have to hidden in A. This is working in chrome but not working in Internet Explorer. In chrome the element is hiding when I drag them to B. But in IE even after I drag the element from A to B, it is showing both in A and B. Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: I wouldn't use a select for this. Drag/drop operations are better suited to block level elements, such as divs. That said, it would help *a lot* to see your actual HTML and JS code

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan, you should use divs for drag & drop, but here is an answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Comment: I used "display: none;" in CSS file, that is working in chrome but not working(not hiding the element) in Internet explorer. Can you suggest if we can use any other attribute which will work in internet explorer.