# Remove working on JQuery options, Hide does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Got this HTML:

```
<select class="trackChanges department" id="DepartmentID_0" name="DepartmentID_0">
    <option value="3">DC</option>
    <option value="5">PL</option>
    <option value="7">SA</option>
</select>
```

Iterating over the options with this javascript & jQuery:

```
var departmentDDL = $(row).find('[id*="DepartmentID_"] > option');

departmentDDL.each(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].innerHTML != "SA") {
        $(this).hide();    // this does not work
        $(this).remove();  // this works
    }
});
```

I'm trying to hide the options, not remove them. Why does one work and not the other?

Comment: It's because support for hiding `option` elements is notoriously flakey across browsers. If you can avoid it, I would.

Comment: remove extra `(` here `if (($(this)[0]` it will work

Comment: @user2486 Good spot, but that's a typo in the question - it's not in the original code.

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra `(` in your `if`, remove it, it will work but only in Chrome with a little buggy behavior.

```js
var departmentDDL = $('[id*="DepartmentID_"] > option');

departmentDDL.each(function() {
  if ($(this)[0].innerHTML != "SA") {
    $(this).hide(); // this does not work
    //$(this).remove();  // this works
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="trackChanges department" id="DepartmentID_0" name="DepartmentID_0">
    <option value="3" >DC</option>
    <option value="5">PL</option>
    <option value="7">SA</option>
</select>
```

**Note** that hiding HTML options has several issues cross browser and won't give expected results in some browsers, for further details check **[How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)**

Comment: "Everything works perfectly" rather overstates the case. This does not work at all in Safari. Only sort of works in Chrome and Firefox (the default value still appears before user click, even though it should be hidden.)

Comment: @DanielBeck I mentioned that under the Snippet.

Comment: Edited answer is slightly better but still misleading: it doesn't work perfectly in Chrome. The original default value is visible before user click, should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

remove extra `(` here `if (($(this)[0]` and it will work

```js
var departmentDDL = $('[id*="DepartmentID_"] > option');

departmentDDL.each(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].innerHTML != "SA") {
        $(this).hide();    // this does not work
        //$(this).remove();  // this works
    }else{
      $(this).parent().val($(this).val()).change();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="trackChanges department" id="DepartmentID_0" name="DepartmentID_0">
    <option value="3">DC</option>
    <option value="5">PL</option>
    <option value="7">SA</option>
</select>
```

It selected in the else part

Comment: See comments on other answer; this does not work correctly in some browsers.

Comment: @DanielBeck : its working with selected item `$(this).parent().val($(this).val()).change();`

Comment: Not in Safari.  I stand corrected though, that it does seem to work in FF and  Chrome.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: I tested in chrome, I don't have safari, also SO dint mention about this. Can you help here for safari. Not for me , for others.

Comment: TBH I think the actual, correct answer to the question was posted by Rory as the very first comment: "It's because support for hiding option elements is notoriously flakey across browsers. If you can avoid it, I would."   That said if you want to edit this answer to mention the safari breakage I'll remove my downvote (I'm outside the time window for retracting a vote without an edit.)

Comment: @Daniel  Have edited if you want to revert your downvote

Comment: ....it still doesn't mention the fact that this doesn't work in Safari, but fine, here are your two points back

Comment: It's not about the point, as I said I don't have safari. And it's also not mentioned by OP. Also you got your 1 point back ;)

Comment: Whether you personally have safari or not isn't relevant.  Neither is whether the OP mentioned it or not.  That the answer, as it stands, is factually incorrect is the point. ("It will work" [except in at least one major current browser])