# Hide default selected item from bootstrap-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-select

I can't seem to find the solution for this. I'm trying to hide the default selected item from a bootstrap-select dropdown like the following:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option selected>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

In this case, 'Mustard' is the default selected value and shouldnt be shown in the dropdown. Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**:
In addition to the accepted answer by ObsidianAge I wanted to note that if you're using this with bootstrap-select.js you should change the CSS to:

```
.dropdown-menu.inner > li.selected {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: "Just like a html select" how does standard HTML hide the selected option?

Comment: Do you only want to hide it in the *dropdown*, or do you want to make it look as though it's not selected either?

Comment: what about an empty <option>or something like select your option ... ?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I only want to hide it in the dropdown

Comment: maybe that's what you're looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want to hide it in the dropdown and **not** hide it as visibly selected by default, you can simply use CSS' **[`display: none`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)** to target the `selected` attribute of the options:

```css
.selectpicker > option[selected] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option selected>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Note that once changed, the user will not be able to (easily) select this option again.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Simple but very effective solution! Stupid that I didn't thought of that earlier.. Many thanks!