# not able to search dynamic data through a search box

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, search, dropdown

I have a drop-down of location/Region, inside that there is a search box.

[image]

As shown in the image, there is a list of places, and then there are regions. The section of region is static and the rest of the places is being fetched from the database. Inside the search box i am able to search for regions but not for dynamic data. One option can be to use DB query but is there a way to perform this functionality without a DB query.

For search, I want each string should match. If user's first letter in search box is "w" then words starting from w should get displayed and not those words who have letter 'w'

```
<select class="selectpicker select-custom-field location" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Location/Region">
    <?php foreach($city as $per_city): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $per_city->city.','.$per_city->state; ?>">
            <?php echo $per_city->city.', '.$per_city->state; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        <option value="Regions">Regions</option>
        <option value="WEST">WEST</option>
        <option value="SOUTHWEST">SOUTHWEST</option>
        <option value="MIDWEST">MIDWEST</option>
        <option value="SOUTHEAST">SOUTHEAST</option>
        <option value="NORTHEAST">NORTHEAST</option>
</select>
```

Sample array that i get from $city is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [city] => Rochester
            [state] => New York
            [country] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [city] => Richmond
            [state] => Virginia
            [country] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [city] => Spokane
            [state] => Washington
            [country] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [city] => Des Moines
            [state] => Iowa
            [country] => 
        )

)
```

Can anyone please tell how this can be done

> Note: If I remove data-live-search-style="begins" from select tag then
>    the search is occuring but the in that search, if user's first letter
>    is "w" then all the words that contain "w" are getting displayed.

Comment: i think you have to pass data-tokens in dynamic option tag

Comment: @Jinesh can u plz tell how i can do that?

Comment: can you print $per_city here? and also tell my which selectpicker you used if any url of your example it will very helpful to me

Comment: There are many strategies how you could do it. You could create your own javascript code, e.g. using regular expressions and set some of the options display property to none. This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css. You could look into jQuery or even bigger solutions such as react, angular and co. You need to choose a strategy yourself, but I would recommend you to go with the flow and investigate how to utilise the famous frameworks for this.

Comment: @Jinesh I have updated the code with the array

Comment: you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options, two best in my opinion are:

- get the $cities as json and then use filter() with javascript
- get it through ajax passing the filter to backends(good when you have a lot of data to be filtered)

Both have drawbacks and advantages:

if you get it via filter passed through ajax then be aware that database will suffer from multiple requests, it can be avoided by giving some delay when user is typing a new filter and/or using cache on backend not to query db multiple times

if you have a lot of data then filtering only with javascript will take some browser memory.

In both solution I suggest returning JSON from backend and create options dynamically with JavaScript, function filtering should be triggered onKeyUp.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this

```
<select class="selectpicker select-custom-field location" data-live-search="true" show-subtext="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Location/Region">
    <?php foreach($city as $per_city): ?>
        <option data-subtext="<?php echo $per_city->city.','.$per_city->state; ?>">
            <?php echo $per_city->city.','.$per_city->state; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        <option value="Regions">Regions</option>
        <option value="WEST">WEST</option>
        <option value="SOUTHWEST">SOUTHWEST</option>
        <option value="MIDWEST">MIDWEST</option>
        <option value="SOUTHEAST">SOUTHEAST</option>
        <option value="NORTHEAST">NORTHEAST</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it is still picking only static data

Comment: https://codepen.io/Rio517/pen/NPLbpP you this link and i change my answer if any helpful to you.

Comment: it is has started to search for dynamic values, but there is still one part left. the search is not happening letter to letter if user types first letter "w" then all the words starting from w should get displayed, but with codepen code, all the words containing "w" are getting displayed on search

Comment: I am sorry i  didn't understood, which html are you referring

Comment: i want to look html

Comment: put this data-live-search-style="startsWith"

Comment: this is my entire code, the only thing extra that i am using is the css and script taken from this link https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/  On downloading the files there is a folder dist, i have used css and js from this folder