# style.display = "none" is not working in IE but works in Other browser

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dropdown. if I select option value in dropdown ,that option should be hidden as result. I attached my piece of code for reference. This working fine in crome but hiding not working in IE-10.
suggest in JavaScript it would be helpful.

I have tried Visibility property also. but not working either.

```js
function dropdown(dd) {
  document.getElementById('mySelect').options[1].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="dropdown(this)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting

Comment: It is bit difficult to scroll and understand your code alignment

Comment: How do you know that it is not working?

Comment: by the way, that code does not hide a thing in firefox

Comment: `document.getElementById('mySelect').options[1].setAttribute('hidden', "hidden");` will hide the second option for example

Comment: @JaromandaX its not hiding either

Comment: Yep, Not even in Internet Explorer 11 - lets face it, IE is broken

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the styling of form elements, different browsers have different levels of support. Being that IE is no longer being developed, and that the last updates were years ago, you're going to find behaviors that just don't work there and never will.

Now, your code does work in browsers that support `option` styling of this kind, it just always sets the second `option` element to be hidden because you are hard-coding `1` as the index. Instead, set the [`.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) of the `select` to be not visible so that you always get the index of whatever `option` is currently selected. And, that will hide the last selected option from showing when the list is subsequently shown, however the `select` will still show that value so you also have to remove that.

```js
document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change", dropdown);

function dropdown() {
  this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.visibility = "hidden"; // Hide on the list
  this.value = ""; // Hide the new value
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: But why? You should also be able to explain why the OPs question is a valid one.

Comment: this does nothing different to the original code at all

Comment: hard coded because of understanding purpose.. but hiding is not working in IE

Comment: @JaromandaX You need to look at the OP's code and my code again then.

Comment: I mean in terms of hiding anything, it does not hide a thing **IN FIREFOX**

Comment: @JaromandaX Then you need to run my code again and look carefully because it does.

Comment: @VijayBharadwaj See updated answer. This does work in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of another way

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="dropdown(this)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

```
<script>
function dropdown(dd) {
  var a = document.getElementById('mySelect');
  a.remove(a.selectedIndex);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just need to hide. not Removing the option

Comment: what's dd in function dropdown(dd)?

Comment: Vijay Bharadwai used this keyword, So I followed his code and modified what exact changes only #vishwa

Comment: Vijay I posted the answer, Please check it is not like permanent remove. You can check and let me know whether this is your expectation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide on change only, another on change if you again the data.

You can try it.

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="dropdown(this)">
    <option>--Select</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

```
<script>
var mySelect = [];
function dropdown(dd) {
  var mySelect1 = document.getElementById('mySelect');
  if(mySelect.text !== undefined && mySelect.index !== '') {
    mySelect1.options.add(new Option(mySelect.text, mySelect.index), mySelect1.options[mySelect.index]);
  }

  var selectedText = mySelect1.options[mySelect1.selectedIndex].text;

  mySelect.text = selectedText;
  mySelect.index = mySelect1.selectedIndex;
  mySelect1.remove(mySelect1.selectedIndex);
}
</script>
```