# Removing <span> tags that are wrapped around <option> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I am trying to hide and show  tags in a dropdown list, which I initially managed to get work in everything bar Internet Explorer.  I then found that wrapping the options that needed to be hidden in  tags solved the IE problem.  But i'm now having an issue with removing them, because the code that I have written also removes the dropdown that they are contained in.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the code so far:

```
function GetMonthsForSelectedYear() {
    var selectedYear = $("#DropDownListYear option:selected").text(),
        currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear(),
        currentMonth = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;

    $("#DropDownListMonth option").each(function() {
        if (selectedYear == currentYear) {
            var option = $(this).index();
            if (option < currentMonth) {
                $(this).wrap('<span>').hide();
            }
        } else {
            $(this).unwrap("<span>").show();
        }
    });
}

$("#DropDownListYear").change(function() {
   GetMonthsForSelectedYear();
});​
```

And here is is in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MGGh9/1/

Thanks.

Comment: It is because you must be not getting correct value in $(this) in else condition. you closed tag 2 times after if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Instead you can just use this:

```
$("#DropDownListMonth option[value=" + title + "]").hide();
```

When you wrap a `<span>`, it wraps the whole `<select>`, not just that `<option>`. And this is an expected behaviour. Moreover, it is not a right way to have anything other than `option` or `optgroup` inside a `select` tag.

#### In your code:

```
function GetMonthsForSelectedYear() {
    var yearOfEntry = $("#DropDownListYear option:selected").text(),
        currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear(),
        currentMonth = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;

    $("#DropDownListMonth option").each(function() {
        if (yearOfEntry == currentYear) {
            var option = $(this).index();
            if (option < currentMonth) {
                $(this).hide();               // «--------- This one
            }
        } else {
            $(this).show();                   // «--------- This one
        }
    });
}

$("#DropDownListYear").change(function() {
   GetMonthsForSelectedYear();
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MGGh9/2/

#### Also Check:

1. [How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)
2. [How can I hide select options with JavaScript? (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398966/how-can-i-hide-select-options-with-javascript-cross-browser)

Comment: "it is not a right way" Well, actually it's invalid HTML markup…

Comment: Well, the above comment is for? And @user1862653 Does this help?

Comment: Ahh, the solution was within the link that you posted: How can I hide select options with JavaScript? (Cross browser).  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that according to the HTML specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element), a `<select>` should only contain `<option>` or `<optgroup>` or script-supporting elements. So you should avoid using invalid `<span>` wrappers and instead just remove & restore your `<option>` elements.

See this answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24439289/1766230 - to this question - [How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css/24439289).