# Feature-detect browser ability to hide select options

Tags: javascript

## Feature-detect ability to hide select options

I want to detect whether a browser can successfully hide option elements inside select controls.

I have [this rather kludgy (half) solution](https://jsfiddle.net/timgrant/bjob7hba/), which meddles with actual elements on the page:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var el = $("form").find("option.hide");
    var supportsHiddenOptions = el.hide().is(":hidden");
    console.log(supportsHiddenOptions);
});

<form>
    <select>
    <option val="1">Static</option>
    <option val="2" class="hide">Hide Me</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This works some of the time: MSIE 11 reports it cannot hide option elements; current Chrome/FF/Opera report they can.

On the other hand, Safari reports it can hide the option, but it does not.

Is there a way to detect whether a browser can hide option elements without manipulating actual DOM elements?

Note, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398966/how-can-i-hide-select-options-with-javascript-cross-browser) shows what you can do instead to hide option elements in MSIE, but I'm interested in detecting the ability simply to hide them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bowser](https://github.com/ded/bowser) to detect browser

Comment: You should never use browser detection, if there is a way to do it using feature detection. Detecting features using the user agent is very error prone.

Comment: I'm aware of browser detection. The question, though, is specifically about feature detection.