# Why this script not works in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, cross-browser

why this script not works in Safari? Chrome, Firefox, Opera is OK...

```
<select id="category_id" name="category_id[]" multiple >
<option value="20">Condo for Sale</option>
<option value="21">Condo in Jomtien</option>
<option value="22">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Condo in Bang Saray</option>
<option value="23">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Condo in East Pattaya</option>
<option value="27">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Condo in Central Pattaya</option>
<option value="28">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Condo in Na Jomtien</option>
</select>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#category_id option[value]").filter(function() {
        return +$(this).val() > 21;
      }).hide();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: What is not working about it? Can you provide an error message or any sort of clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide select options with JavaScript? (Cross browser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398966/how-can-i-hide-select-options-with-javascript-cross-browser)

Comment: `category_id option[value]` might not be a valid ID value. I rate this question a two out of seven.

Comment: Not all browsers allow you to hide options. So you need to remove them.

Comment: @epascarello great, remove() function is better!