# Option display does not work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have two drop down menus. Option of second drop down are shown on the selection of first drop down.

It works perfect on chrome however on safari/iphone, it doesn't work. I searched around the web to find a fix and learned about safari doesn't let you hide the options. So I tried coming up with a solution, which seems to work somewhat but not quite. How can I fix adjust the code to correct this across all browsers?

```js
// get first dropdown and bind change event handler
$('#p-city').change(function() {
  // get optios of second dropdown and cache it
  var $options = $('#p-nhb')
    // update the dropdown value if necessary
    .val('')
    // get options
    .find('option')
    // show all of the initially
    .show();

  // IF SAFARI
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    var $options = $('#p-nhb').val('').find('option').append();
  }

  // check current value is not 0
  if (this.value != '0')
    $options
    // filter out options which is not corresponds to the first option
    .not('[data-val="' + this.value + '"],[data-val=""]')
    // hide them
    .hide();

  // IF SAFARI
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    $options.not('[data-val="' + this.value + '"],[data-val=""]').detach();
  }
})
$('#p-city').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<select name="property_city" id="p-city">
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city" selected>New York City</option>
  <option class="button" value="">All</option>
  <option class="button" value="dallas-tx">Dallas, TX</option>
  <option class="button" value="las-vegas">Las Vegas, NV</option>
  <option class="button" value="los-angeles">Los Angeles, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="miami">Miami, FL</option>
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city">New York City, NY</option>
  <option class="button" value="san-francisco">San Francisco, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="seattle-wa">Seattle, WA</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<select name="property_nhb[]" id="p-nhb" multiple>
  <option class="button">All</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="beverly-hills" >Beverly Hills</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="santa-monica" >Santa Monica</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="hialea" >Hialea</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="little-havana">Little Havana</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="north-miami">North Miami</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="south-beach">South Beach</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="chelsea">Chelsea</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="harlem">Harlem</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="noho">NoHo</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="soho">SoHo</option>
</select>
</p>
```

**UPDATE**

I've noticed another function of mines also doesnt work in safari --

```
$("#search-tabs").on('click','li', function(e) {
  $('.searchbox').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

So I guess it's safe to say ".hide" and ".show" dont work in safari, what is a simple alternative without having to rewrite a bunch of code?

**UPDATE 2**

This works to for .hide (.show = 'block') but not for the select options -

```
  .css('display', 'none');
```

**UPDATE 3**

The drop downs before rendered --

```
<select name="property_city" class="form-control" id="p-city">
<?php
$terms = get_terms( "city-type", array( 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0  ){
echo "<option class='button' value='new-york-city'>New York City</option>";
echo "<option class='button' value=''>All</option>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         echo "<option class='button' value='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</option>";
     }
 }
?>
  </select>

<label>Neighborhood</label>
<?php $taxonomyName = "city-type"; 
$parent_terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false ) );   
echo "<select name='property_nhb[]' class='form-control' id='p-nhb' style='border-left: 1px solid #000 !important;' multiple>";
echo "<option class='button'>All</option>";
foreach ( $parent_terms as $pterm ) {
    //Get the Child terms
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo "<option data-val='" . $pterm->slug . "' value='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</option>"; 
    }
}
echo "</select>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398966/how-can-i-hide-select-options-with-javascript-cross-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround that will surely works across all browsers, could be cached options list, used then to append into second select box.

```js
var select_clone = $('#p-nhb option');


$('#p-city')
  .change(function() {
    $('#p-nhb').html(select_clone.filter('[data-val="' + this.value + '"]'));
  })
  .change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<select name="property_city" id="p-city">
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city" selected>New York City</option>
  <option class="button" value="">All</option>
  <option class="button" value="dallas-tx">Dallas, TX</option>
  <option class="button" value="las-vegas">Las Vegas, NV</option>
  <option class="button" value="los-angeles">Los Angeles, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="miami">Miami, FL</option>
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city">New York City, NY</option>
  <option class="button" value="san-francisco">San Francisco, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="seattle-wa">Seattle, WA</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<select name="property_nhb[]" id="p-nhb" multiple>
  <option class="button">All</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="beverly-hills" >Beverly Hills</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="santa-monica" >Santa Monica</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="hialea" >Hialea</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="little-havana">Little Havana</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="north-miami">North Miami</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="south-beach">South Beach</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="chelsea">Chelsea</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="harlem">Harlem</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="noho">NoHo</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="soho">SoHo</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Here is alternative solution with hidden select, due to Your comment about duplicated list bug:

```js
var select_clone = $('<select>')
  .html($('#p-nhb option'))
  .hide()
  .insertAfter('#p-nhb');

$('#p-city')
  .change(function() {
    $('#p-nhb').html(select_clone.find('[data-val="' + this.value + '"]').clone());
  })
  .change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<select name="property_city" id="p-city">
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city" selected>New York City</option>
  <option class="button" value="">All</option>
  <option class="button" value="dallas-tx">Dallas, TX</option>
  <option class="button" value="las-vegas">Las Vegas, NV</option>
  <option class="button" value="los-angeles">Los Angeles, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="miami">Miami, FL</option>
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city">New York City, NY</option>
  <option class="button" value="san-francisco">San Francisco, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="seattle-wa">Seattle, WA</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<select name="property_nhb[]" id="p-nhb" multiple>
  <option class="button">All</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="beverly-hills" >Beverly Hills</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="santa-monica" >Santa Monica</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="hialea" >Hialea</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="little-havana">Little Havana</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="north-miami">North Miami</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="south-beach">South Beach</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="chelsea">Chelsea</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="harlem">Harlem</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="noho">NoHo</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="soho">SoHo</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Comment: for some reason though it shows the options in the second drop down twice though. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: @RichJ is that happens in the Safari or all browsers? Beacuse demo is working. I have one more idea for fix if it's Safari only bug.

Comment: All the browsers @instead

Comment: @RichJ Please check my edit then. Second code snippet

Comment: Same issue, could be in my php code? Even though before I didn't have this problem only the safari issue.

Comment: @RichJ My demo is working - both acutally. Problem is clearly somewhere else in Your website scripts. It's not PHP issue.

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason, on the page, I had to put the javascript after the dropdowns.

Comment: Only issue I have is when changing the first drop down, whenever the second drop down changes, the first option appears blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158553/discussion-between-instead-and-rich-j).

Answer (score 1):

I would use something where you update values from a backing hidden select and populate them based on values. Because this will be a simple cross browser solution

```
<p>
<select name="property_city" id="p-city">
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city" selected>New York City</option>
  <option class="button" value="">All</option>
  <option class="button" value="dallas-tx">Dallas, TX</option>
  <option class="button" value="las-vegas">Las Vegas, NV</option>
  <option class="button" value="los-angeles">Los Angeles, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="miami">Miami, FL</option>
  <option class="button" value="new-york-city">New York City, NY</option>
  <option class="button" value="san-francisco">San Francisco, CA</option>
  <option class="button" value="seattle-wa">Seattle, WA</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<select name="property_nhb[]" id="p-nhb" multiple>
</select>
<select name="property_nhb[]" id="p-nhb-back" style="display:none" multiple>
  <option class="button">All</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="beverly-hills" >Beverly Hills</option>
  <option data-val="los-angeles" value="santa-monica" >Santa Monica</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="hialea" >Hialea</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="little-havana">Little Havana</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="north-miami">North Miami</option>
  <option data-val="miami" value="south-beach">South Beach</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="chelsea">Chelsea</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="harlem">Harlem</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="noho">NoHo</option>
  <option data-val="new-york-city" value="soho">SoHo</option>
</select>
</p>
```

And then a simple javascript

```
// get first dropdown and bind change event handler
$('#p-city').change(function() {
  // get optios of second dropdown and cache it
  var $options = $('#p-nhb')
    // update the dropdown value if necessary
    .val('')
    // get options
    .find('option')
    // show all of the initially
    .remove();


    $("#p-nhb").append($('#p-nhb-back option[data-val="' + this.value + '"],[data-val=""]'));
})
$('#p-city').trigger('change');
```

It works fine for me. Here is a jsfiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/cckhgw5g/

Comment: The problem though is that my drop downs values are dynamic. It's for wordpress so I cant create a bunch of drop downs.

Comment: @RichJ, in any case you would have pulled down those values from some place? You can do that for your backing select instead. Because whatever logic you were thinking to apply earlier. Should be applicable now