# How can I hide multiple options from the select tag with javascript and class

Tags: javascript

Please I need help in hiding particular options from select tag based on a particular condition with javascript and class.
Here is my code

```
 <select>
    <option class="dis">Cat</b></option>
    <option class="dis">Dog</option>
    <option class="dis">Snake</option>
    <option class="dis">Ostrich</option>
    <option class="dis">Lion</option>
 </select>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dis");
    doIt(elements, false);

function doIt(elements, status) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].disabled = status;
    }
}
```

Using classes and arrays how can I hide the above options instead of disabling them?

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` in some browsers. Choices are enable/disable or remove/replace. Or use a `<select>` replacement script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide select options with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398966/how-can-i-hide-select-options-with-javascript-cross-browser)

Comment: If all options have the same class, why not put the class on the `select` and hide that element?

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like that...

```js
(function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('select.dis').forEach(sd=>
    {
    sd.htmlOps = sd.innerHTML
    sd.status = false
    sd.doIt = function(status)
      {
      if (sd.status !== status)
        {
        if (status) sd.length = 0
        else        sd.innerHTML = sd.htmlOps
        sd.status = status
        } 
      }
    }) 
  }
)()

const mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select')

btShow.onclick = () => mySelect.doIt(false)
btHide.onclick = () => mySelect.doIt(true)
```

```html
<button id="btHide">hide</button>
<button id="btShow">show</button>
<br><br>
<select id="my-select" class="dis" >
  <option value="a">Cat</option>
  <option value="b">Dog</option>
  <option value="c">Snake</option>
  <option value="d">Ostrich</option>
  <option value="e">Lion</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a short way to remove whatever options you want

```js
 // Remove Cat option
 document.getElementById('select').remove(0);
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option class="dis">Cat</b></option>
    <option class="dis">Dog</option>
    <option class="dis">Snake</option>
    <option class="dis">Ostrich</option>
    <option class="dis">Lion</option>
 </select>
```

If you want to keep only the two first options use a boucle like I do in the code bellow.

And if you'd like to add your option back adapte the exemple I gave using `.add(option)`

```js
const select =  document.getElementById('select')
for (i = select.length - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
    select.remove(i);
}

function add() {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = "Lion";
  select.add(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option class="dis">Cat</b></option>
    <option class="dis">Dog</option>
    <option class="dis">Snake</option>
    <option class="dis">Ostrich</option>
    <option class="dis">Lion</option>
 </select>
 
 <button onclick="add()"> ADD Lion option</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

This may or may not work on *all* browsers, but it works on most:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dis");
    doIt(elements, false);

function doIt(elements, status) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].disabled = status;
        elements[i].style.display = status ? null : 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
 <select>
    <option class="dis">Cat</option>
    <option class="dis">Dog</option>
    <option class="dis">Snake</option>
    <option class="dis">Ostrich</option>
    <option class="dis">Lion</option>
 </select>
```