# Filter select option dropdown when user clicks

Tags: javascript, filter

So I want to filter `select option` dropdown based on what user clicks by id:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#item-types').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const categoriesSelect = document.querySelector('#item-categories')
            const categoriesOptions = Array.from(categoriesSelect.options);
            const selectType = item.dataset.typeId;

            function findMatches(search, categoriesOptions) {
                return categoriesOptions.filter(option => {
                    return option.value.match(search);
                });
            }

            categoriesOptions.forEach(option => {
                option.remove();
                option.selected = false;
            });
            const matchArray = findMatches(selectType, categoriesOptions);
            categoriesSelect.append(...matchArray);
        });
    });
```

```html
<ul>
   <li id="item-types" data-type-id="1">
       <a href="#">
           <div>Type1</div>
       </a>
   </li>
   <li id="item-types" data-type-id="2">
       <a href="#">
           <div>Type2</div>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>

<select id="item-categories">
    <option value="1">category1</option>
    <option value="1">category2</option>
    <option value="1">category3</option>
    <option value="2">category4</option>
    <option value="2">category5</option>
</select>
```

But now when I click any of the list items for the first item it filters out okay, but when I click it second time it returns empty array for `options`.

Comment: Perrhaps you are looking for the [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element?

Comment: Do you want to remove the item from the dropdown which is selected from `<li>` by matching data-type-id with option value?

Comment: @NavnathJadhav for example user clicks ```<li>``` with data-type-id = 1 and then I want to remove ```option values``` where = 2,3,4,5 and leave only ```option value=1```. Now this code works only when I click ```<li>``` for the first time, but when I click it second time it returns empty ```option``` dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with this

I save the options and add them when clicked

I also simplified your UL. You could add a cursor:pointer to it if you need

I am not hiding the options because it is poorly supported

[How can I hide select options with JavaScript? (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398966/how-can-i-hide-select-options-with-javascript-cross-browser)

```js
const categoriesSelect = document.getElementById('item-categories')
const originalOptions = [...categoriesSelect.options].slice(0); // copy
document.getElementById('item-types').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li");
  if (tgt.classList.contains("item-type")) {
    const selectType = tgt.dataset.typeId;
    categoriesSelect.length=0; // remove all
    originalOptions.filter(opt => opt.value == selectType).forEach(opt => categoriesSelect.append(opt))
  }
  categoriesSelect.selectedIndex = 0; // select the first
});
```

```html
<ul id="item-types">
  <li class="item-type" data-type-id="1">Type1</li>
  <li class="item-type" data-type-id="2">Type2</li>
</ul>

<select id="item-categories">
  <option value="1">category1</option>
  <option value="1">category2</option>
  <option value="1">category3</option>
  <option value="2">category4</option>
  <option value="2">category5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks it works, but now I have one more question. For Example if you click Type1 it selects last item from dropdown category3 is it possible to make that it would select first item from dropdown and display it category1?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that you remove the options completely if they don't fit the search criteria and then when you filter again, you filter from the ones already previously filtered. Because of that you get the empty array.

Instead you need to come up with a way to remember the initial options and filter always from those. You could store the options in a variable for example. Or simply hide the non-matching ones with CSS instead of removing them completely.

Comment: Yea I thought about that but I dont know how to achieve that :)

Comment: Well that's a different issue, but I'm sure you're capable of it. You already take the options into a variable so you could just take them to a variable before the callback. Though you probably shouldn't remove the options in that case.

With CSS you would need to pass a class to the options. If the option doesn't match, the style should have `display: hidden;`

Comment: @tuomokar You will have problems [hiding options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398966/how-can-i-hide-select-options-with-javascript-cross-browser)

Comment: Oh that's interesting, didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const allCategoryOptionsStore = [...document.getElementById("item-categories").options];
  // parent event listener
  document.getElementById("types").addEventListener("click", handleOnClick);

  function handleOnClick(e){
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.tagName.toUpperCase() == "DIV") {
      const dataTypeId = tgt.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("data-type-id");
      const selectCategories = document.getElementById("item-categories");
      selectCategories.options.length = 0;
      allCategoryOptionsStore.filter(opt => opt.value === dataTypeId).forEach(opt =>selectCategories.options.add(opt));
    }
  }
```

```html
<ul id="types">
  <li data-type-id="1">
    <a>
      <div>Type 1</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-type-id="2">
    <a>
      <div>Type 2</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-type-id="3">
    <a>
      <div>Type 3</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-type-id="4">
    <a>
      <div>Type 4</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<select id="item-categories">
  <option value="1">category 1</option>
  <option value="2">category 2</option>
  <option value="2">category 2</option>
  <option value="3">category 3</option>
  <option value="3">category 3</option>
  <option value="1">category 1</option>
  <option value="4">category 4</option>
</select>
```